What prevents God from doing evil to jivas?
I have this strange question.What prevents Lord from doing evil to jivas? We see Lord Indra misusing his power.But why doesnt God do evil? There is no one who can punish Lord for his actions then why cant he do evil to enjoy himself? Is there any reason?
I want answers more from Dwaita perspective..Even Advaitins may answer from vyavaharika perspective..

'evil' is a western concept of thinking. There is sattva, rajas, and tamas. That which leads you away from the Lord is tamas. That which leads you towards the Lord is sattva. Sattva, rajas, and tamas only exist within the sensual universe. The Lord is beyond the sensual universe. What you are asking is not logical. You are asking - Why doesn't He who is beyond cause, cause evil...
